# ROS 2 Humble FastDDS Monitor

Tags: communication, ros2, ros-humble

I struggle to use the eProsima FastDDS Monitor on Humble. I managed to make it work with Vulcanexus Docker image; however, if I follow the guide from 2022 Roscon presentation, I don't see any network traffic in the Monitor tool.

To summarize my setup:

- Humble
- Building fastdds from source with
  `colcon build --cmake-args -DFASTDDS_STATISTICS=on`
- Sourcing environments:
  `source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bas`
  `source <path to fastdds_ws>/install/setup.bash`
- Enabling Statistics Module

  `export FASTDDS_STATISTICS="HISTORY_LATENCY_TOPIC;NETWORK_LATENCY_TOPIC; PUBLICATION_THROUGHPUT_TOPIC; SUBSCRIPTION_THROUGHPUT_TOPIC;RTPS_SENT_TOPIC;RTPS_LOST_TOPIC;HEARTBEAT_COUNT_TOPIC; ACKNACK_COUNT_TOPIC;NACKFRAG_COUNT_TOPIC;GAP_COUNT_TOPIC;DATA_COUNT_TOPIC;RESENT_DATAS_TOPIC; SAMPLE_DATAS_TOPIC;PDP_PACKETS_TOPIC;EDP_PACKETS_TOPIC;DISCOVERY_TOPIC;PHYSICAL_DATA_TOPIC"`
- Running `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker` node and the Fast DDS Monitor in a different tab.

The difference in the Monitor's behavior is while I can list the connected Entities, there's no traffic in the Statistics tab, and I don't see any device under the Physical tab. This, in my opinion, indicated that the talker was not, in fact, launched with the statistics enabled. Did someone succeed to launch Fast DDS Monitor with Humble?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was related to the eProsima/Fast-DDS version. After rolling back to v2.6.2, which is mentioned in the Roscon presentation, I got the expected behavior.